# Validation in datePicker textbox

Tags: jquery, html, validation, textbox, datepicker

[image: Textbox having date field]

I have a textbox field called "Expires on" and I am using DatePicker

```
 $("#sfExpiresOn").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    minDate: 0
                })
```

Here, I need validation  because use can simply add random number here like

[image]

How can i prevent user to add random number values. (I don't need HTML 5 validation.)

Thank You

Comment: If you would like to use a plugin, check [here](http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html)

Comment: U can use maskedEditExtender of ajax.... that will allow to inset text but only that text which is acceptable according to format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add the property

```
ReadOnly="true"
```

to your textbox?

Simply, add the following code to your script

```
$("#sfExpiresOn").attr( 'readOnly' , 'true' );
```

Comment: Glad to help :) Please accept my answer if you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

If u don't want to use ReadOnly feature the u can use `MaskedEditExtender` of `AJAX`. Lets say if i want my calender date to be like DD/MM/YYY then it will be like this

```
<Ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender3" TargetControlID="txtdate"
   Mask="99/99/9999" MessageValidatorTip="true" OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
   OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" MaskType="Date" 
   UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear"
   DisplayMoney="Left" AcceptNegative="Left" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" 
   runat="server">
```